# Linq error when using let

Tags: linq, let

I have the following linq query and it is giving the following error: A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

```
from sdc in ScheduleDestinationCaches
let twins = from gt in GetTwins(72)
join ssFilter in ScheduleStops on sdc.CarrierID equals ssFilter.CarrierID
join ssLookup in ScheduleStops on sdc.CityID equals ssLookup.CityID
join sc in ScheduleCarriers on ssLookup.CarrierID equals sc.CarrierID
where twins.Contains(ssFilter.StopID ) || ssFilter.StopID == 72
select sc
```

any ideas?

By the way I'm using linqpad

Comment: Please show `GetTwins(72)`

Comment: from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx it looks like you're missing a second `from` clause after the `let` cause.  Yes I realize it's for C# syntax, but in this case, it's basically identical except the semicolon at the end.

Comment: It is complaining about `from gt in GetTwins(72)` which doesn't have a select.

Comment: The GetTwins is a user defined function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add some indentation:

```
from sdc in ScheduleDestinationCaches
let twins = from gt in GetTwins(72)
            join ssFilter in ScheduleStops on sdc.CarrierID equals ssFilter.CarrierID
            join ssLookup in ScheduleStops on sdc.CityID equals ssLookup.CityID
            join sc in ScheduleCarriers on ssLookup.CarrierID equals sc.CarrierID
            where twins.Contains(ssFilter.StopID ) || ssFilter.StopID == 72
            select sc
```

Can you see the issue now? Adding `from` as an assignment to `let`-defined variable starts new LINQ expression, which end with `select sc`. This makes the outer query not to have `select` clause at all!

I think you're looking for

```
from sdc in ScheduleDestinationCaches
let twins = GetTwins(72)
join ssFilter in ScheduleStops on sdc.CarrierID equals ssFilter.CarrierID
join ssLookup in ScheduleStops on sdc.CityID equals ssLookup.CityID
join sc in ScheduleCarriers on ssLookup.CarrierID equals sc.CarrierID
where twins.Contains(ssFilter.StopID ) || ssFilter.StopID == 72
select sc
```

**Comments-based update**

```
from sdc in ScheduleDestinationCaches
let twins = GetTwins(72).Select(x => x.Id)
join ssFilter in ScheduleStops on sdc.CarrierID equals ssFilter.CarrierID
join ssLookup in ScheduleStops on sdc.CityID equals ssLookup.CityID
join sc in ScheduleCarriers on ssLookup.CarrierID equals sc.CarrierID
where twins.Contains(ssFilter.StopID ) || ssFilter.StopID == 72
select sc
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see and understand the difference. Now I'm getting a different error: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LINQPad.User.GetTwinsResult>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LINQPad.User.GetTwinsResult>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int>'

Comment: That's because `GetTwins` returns a collection of objects, and you're trying to check if it contains an `int` value. That will not work.

Comment: That make sense. How can I emulate a select in?

Comment: Add `Select(x => x.Id)` (or whatever the property name is) call after `GetTwins`.